# How to validate Vonage webhook signature in Typescript using Vonage sdk?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webhooks, vonage

I have a webhook that handles inbound SMS using webhooks. I need to verify that the request comes from Vonage by verifying the signature in the request.

The following link indicates how to proceed : [Vonage documentation](https://developer.vonage.com/en/getting-started/concepts/signing-messages)

Here, a full example is given : [Github code](https://github.com/Vonage/vonage-node-code-snippets/blob/eb78577ee90266da1a03421927fb45af82b7d1cd/sms/verify-signed-sms-express.js)

Unfortunately, when I try to do the same, the code show the following error.

```
Property 'generateSignature' does not exist on type 'typeof Vonage'.
```

When I make a search (`grep -r generateSignature`) in the sdk code in node_modules, the search gives no result for "generateSignature", there is no mention of this function in their sdk.

The documentation seems wrong.

How to validate the "sig" parameter in the request payload for inbound SMS using Vonage sdk in Typescript/NodeJS?

Comment: The Vonage support team confirmed that the documentation is outdated. They are currently updating their documentation.